# How to click in a place with exaxt coordination in selenium python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, coordinates, offset, exacttarget

I want to click in exactly pointed place in the image below.

I tried by actions in selenium. But it doesn't work like in below :

```py
mouse_tracker = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mouse-tracker")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(mouse_tracker, 8, 0)
        .perform()
```

Comment: I don't see that you perform click in provided code. You just moved to element with offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
mouse_tracker = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mouse-tracker")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(mouse_tracker, 8, 0).click().perform()
```